# Xamarin Forms. How can I bind picker's selected item to be displayed in picker field on switching view?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, picker

I'm having problem with picker's bindable SelectedItem and ItemsSource, when I have a picker filled with values from database.

On pushing view with binding context as a class,

```
async private void ListaRachunkow_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new RachunekDetails() { BindingContext = e.SelectedItem as Rachunek });
        }
    }
```

with picker being one of the fields,

```
<Picker x:Name="kategoriaPicker" SelectedItem="{Binding Kategoria}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

there is no selected item appearing (empty field). Pikcer is being filled with list gathered from another class's database.

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        PopulatePicker();
    }
    async private void PopulatePicker()
    {
        List<Kategorie> kategories = await App.KategoriaDatabase.GetKategorieAsync();
        List<string> katestringlist = new List<string>();
        foreach (Kategorie k in kategories)
            katestringlist.Add(k.NazwaKategorii.ToString());
        kategoriaPicker.ItemsSource = katestringlist;
    }
```

Kategorie class has 2 fields. one is its integer ID, the other one is its name. I am stuck in here, trying to figure out how to solve this issue, but I can't find any solution.

What this part of app does is that there is a listview filled with items from Rachunek's class database. If an item is selected, it pushes this item to new view where you can edit it or delete it.

What I dont understand is that there is a second picker that is filled statically in view constructor methode, below InitializeComponent(), is bound in the same way and works perfectly.

```
    typPlatnosciPicker.ItemsSource= new List<string>{
            "Karta",
            "Gotówka",
            "Inny"
    };
```

Target platform is Android.

Comment: where is Kategoria set?  Is it one of the items contained in the Picker's ItemSource?

Comment: Kategoria is a Rachunek's class field.

Comment: is it referencing an object that is also contained in the Picker's ItemSource?  If not then it's not going to work

Comment: Yes, its string is the same as one of the Picker's Items.